# What is a good way to make a class unserializable?

Tags: java, serialization, coding-style

Java contains a lot of classes (like in Swing) which implement the [dreaded and error prone](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things1/index.html) [interface `Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

If you implement, say, a new `TableModel` by extending `AbstractTableModel`, the new model must be serializable but what if it contains internal data types which aren't serializable and which don't have to be since you don't plan to use this feature anyway?

In such a case, tools like [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) go crazy. The either complain that "Class `Foo` defines non-transient non-serializable instance field `bar`".

So I make that field `transient` just to get "The field `Foo.bar` is transient but isn't set by deserialization"

Is it possible to say "No, this class isn't serializable, and I don't want it to be" in such a way that you don't get any errors in tools like Sonar?

Comment: Does Sonar support suppression of a warning for an individual class? In IntelliJ it gives you the option to add a @SuppressWarning to the class for you for this check.

Comment: Sonar just runs FindBugs, PMD and CheckStyle on your code and aggregates the results. So a solution which keeps those three quiet would work for me. `@SuppressWarning` works as expected. There are also plugins which allow to ignore warnings by things like file name, path or String pattern.

Comment: Isn't that what 'transient' is for?

Comment: @EJP: I already answered that in my question

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Quoting from this [JavaRevisited article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/top-10-java-serialization-interview.html) (see #8):

> To avoid java serialization you need to implement writeObject() and readObject() method in your Class and need to throw NotSerializableException from those method.

So you just need to paste this into your class:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream) throws java.io.IOException {
    throw new java.io.NotSerializableException( getClass().getName() );
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    throw new java.io.NotSerializableException( getClass().getName() );
}
```

Comment: Wow, did not know about `NotSerializableException`

Comment: I verified this solution and it works. Sonar, FindBugs and PMD all seem to check for `NotSerializableException`.

Comment: Sounds strange: Implement an Interface Serializable and throw a NotSerializableException, while serializing. The only way I see is to create a Proxy-Class, which is NOT serializable an delegate all methods to the concrete implementation. But that is something like nuking a tiny little bird.

Comment: If you are reading this intending to silence PMD warnings on transient fields beware that if the class sub-classes something that implements Serializable, and you make your sub-class also implement Serializable then you will end up with a new PMD warning that sub-classes should not reimplement interfaces. Have not spotted a workaround yet.

Answer (score 6):

implement `writeObject()` and `readObject()` methods to throw `NotSerializableException`

or

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/security.html#4214

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that?

```
@SuppressFBWarnings(justification = "This field need to be transient")
private transient SomeObject myTransientField;
```

You will suppress the Findbug warning. You also can specify the validation type you want to suprres like:

```
@SuppressFBWarnings("SE_TRANSIENT_FIELD_NOT_RESTORED")
```

The complete list is there: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html

Comment: I see what you're trying to do but I only have `transient` because FindBugs complains about the field not being serializable. What I'm looking for is a way to tell Sonar that the class can't and won't be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

I can think about implementing method `private void writeObject()` as following:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not serializable!!!");
}
```

Alternatively you can implement `Externalizable` and and write similiar implementation of `writeExternal()`

Both are not "good" methods but just workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

The answers I see here actually merely answer whether it is possible to prevent serialization or deserialization of some class marked serializable. The question was a different one, though:

'Is it possible to say "No, this class isn't serializable, and I don't want it to be" in such a way that you don't get any errors in tools like Sonar?'

(So I wonder about those many up-votes on those answers...)

Google'ing around the answer seems to be 'no', Sonar can be told that such a class is a "false positive", but that requires tinkering with Sonar. Developers who develop code inspected by other people's Sonar cannot benefit from that possibility.

And as the question actually asks for a solution for other tools "like Sonar", too, the answer in general cannot be "Yes" --- for sure some such tool will insist on "implements Serializable + has non-serializable non transient field" to mean trouble.

Comment: Oh, I see, the original poster tried it and the tools in question actually do look for that exception. So the answers do indeed imply a solution...